Sonarqube's process taking too much time
I'm actually on a test server. I've installed sonarqube on my docker compose to test my files on gitlab. So I've downloaded 2 runners (sonarqube runner & openjdk17 runner). First time when Ive started the sonarqube, it was working and downloading configuration files from repsy and central then stopped. Now it's not even working and hang on the process.
Is it a RAM problem or something ?
Here is my gitlab-ci.yml
image: maven:3-openjdk-17

stages:
#    - compile
    - sonarqube_stage

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository"
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --settings ci_settings.xml "

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

sonarqube_ci_stanza:                                                                # free name
  image: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:${SONAR_SCANNER_CLI_VERSION}
  stage: sonarqube_stage                                                            # free name
  variables:
    SONAR_PROJECT_BASE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR"
  script:
    - /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey="$CI_PROJECT_NAME"   
  tags:                                                                             
    - sonarqube   

#compile_job:
#  stage: compile
#  script:
#    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS package -P develop
#  tags:
#    - openjdk17
#  artifacts:
#    expire_in: 1 hour
#    paths:
#      - target





And the caption of my sonnar :
https://i.sstatic.net/4atQfSFL.png
thank you very much :)
I've tried to see if the problem was on my docker compose but i didn't touch it and it was working at first

check volume(pv and PVC) persmissions and clean the data .
In my scenario i have used local storage class , pod taken time due to /bitnami/postgress not able to create,
so create local pv and pvc and address in values.yaml

